# How to convert month number to name between date and year in php?

Tags: php

```
$dates = '2019-11-15 11:25:12';    
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dates));

current output: 15-11-2019

expected output: 15-Nov-2019
```

In this code I am have datetime and I want to change month number to name between date and year. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the date format from `'d-m-Y'` to `'d-M-Y'`.
All date format letters are explained here for future reference: https://www.adminschoice.com/php-date-format

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change format string:

```
$dates = '2019-11-15 11:25:12';    
$date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($dates));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use uppercase M or F for month
M is the first three letter while F is full name of the month

```
$date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($dates));
```

or

```
$date = date('d-F-Y', strtotime($dates));
```